# how can I fetch this data to html page using angular.js?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
var gamedataRef = firebase.database().ref('gamedata');
gamedataRef.on('child_added', function(data) {
    $scope.abc = data.val().textgame;
});
```

I have to find this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Firebase data is loaded asynchronously. This is great, because it allows the browser to continue being responsive while the data is being loaded. But unfortunately it also means that AngularJS is not expecting updates anymore by the time the data comes back.

The solution is to tell AngularJS when the data comes back, with for example `$timeout()`:

```
var gamedataRef = firebase.database().ref('gamedata');
gamedataRef.on('child_added', function(data) {
    $timeout(function(){
        $scope.abc = data.val().textgame;
    });
});
```

You might also want to have a look at AngularFire, an open-source binding library that solves this problem and a lot of others you're likely to run into.

Comment: hii Frank ., i got the data but i am not  able to print the id of separate data can you suggest me how can i fetch data ?